# Word To Describe Changing the Rules of Some Situation For An End Goal

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to define the act of changing the rules of some situation frequently until one party gets what they want?

Comment: Are you thinking of "moving the goalposts"?

Comment: I guess that is it! It didn't come to me at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s likely that you’re thinking of “[*moving the goalposts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts)”:

> **Moving the goalposts** (or **shifting the goalposts**) is a metaphor, derived from goal-based sports, that means to change the criterion (goal) of a process or competition while it is still in progress, in such a way that the new goal offers one side an intentional advantage or disadvantage.

(*quoted from Wikipedia, at link*)